# IPython doesn't work in Django shell

Tags: python, django, osx-snow-leopard

I've just recently switched over to using 64-bit Python 2.6.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard). IPython won't work with Django anymore, but IPython works from the command-line.

The error says:

```
    shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
```

I could use the `./manage.py --plain` option, but it's not really a fix. Any help very gratefully received!

Comment: What version of iPython do you have?

Comment: Also, you can use bpython with django, meanwhile: http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/12/using-bpython-shell-with-django-and-some-ipython-features-you-should-know/

Comment: I have IPython 0.11.bzr.r1205 . bpython looks interesting, thanks for the tip

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPython doesn't find the Shell.IPShell class ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262938/ipython-doesnt-find-the-shell-ipshell-class)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IPython 0.11 has a different API, for which a fix exists in the last Django versions.

For older Django versions, you can use IPython 0.10, which does work:

```
pip install ipython==0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work when you run it from Python interactive console?

```
import IPython; IPython.Shell
```

Comment: I get the same answer as when trying to runserver without the --plain flag.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and solved this issue by applying the patches for the Django bug. - [IPython doesn't find the Shell.IPShell class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262938/ipython-doesnt-find-the-shell-ipshell-class)