# IPython doesn't find the Shell.IPShell class

Tags: python, django, ipython

After installing Django, I followed [the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) Playing with the API. When I run the following command.

```
python manage.py shell
```

I got this error message.

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", 
  line 29, in handle_noargs
    shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
```

I checked that I have Shell.py module, and IPShell class inside it.

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/IPython/Shell.py

```
class IPShell:
    """Create an IPython instance."""
```

What's wrong with this? My IPython/Python/OS is as follows.

- Mac OS X 10.6.5
- Python 2.6.1
- IPython version 0.10.1

### ADDED

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.Shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
>>> print IPython.__file__
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py
```

### SOLVED

With ma3 and Ignacio's help, I could solve this issue.

1. Remove site-package/IPython and site-package/ipython*.egg
2. sudo easy_install ipython to fresh install the IPython
3. Apply the patch to the django's shell.py as Ignacio linked.

   ```
       try:
           shell = IPython.InteractiveShell()
       except AttributeError:
           # IPython < 0.11
           # Explicitly pass an empty list as arguments, because otherwise IPython
           # would use sys.argv from this script.
           shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
       shell.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: How did you install Python? That's not the standard directory python is installed in.

Comment: @ma3 : I didn't install Python, with Mac, Python is pre-installed.

Comment: Ok, you're using the OS's python 2.6. How did you install IPython? I have OSX 10.6.5, Python 2.6, IPython 0.10.1, and my `__init__.py` file is very different from yours. Yours looks like it might be from an IPython 0.11 branch.

Comment: @ma3 : Well, just download the source, and run 'python setup.py install'.

Comment: The source for 0.10.1? or for the 0.11 branch that's still in development and isn't complete yet? Why not simply `easy_install ipython`? That will get you 0.10.1, the most current stable version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [change](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8ce576641c4d1d244944fcb4c6b244efde4aa1df/IPython/__init__.py) was made to IPython back in August 19, 2009 that removed this name, and Django hasn't caught up yet. So, Django bug.

**EDIT:**

And [here it is](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12735).

Comment: However, I got the same error with python REPL. as I added in the question. So, Am I 'not' supposed to run IPython.Shell directly?

Comment: Correct. The name no longer exists. Apply one of the fixes in the bug report to your Django source.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an official commit from django-extensions repo at GitHub:

[Django-Extensions GitHub repo](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/commit/5bd6448df48131fd3f32dda00f74148fc0cc3d88)

You can install it by doing this:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git
$ cd django-extensions
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

For IPython 0.11.dev is fix that:

```
from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import IPythonApp
app = IPythonApp(argv=[])
app.start()
```